# Android playing sound in game

Tags: android, opengl-es, audio

I'm making game in OpenGL 2.0 and I want to play multiple sounds in same time.
I have tried:
SoundPool-but my soundtracks are very large and i can't load them.
MediaPlayer-this work ok but than FPS are very low.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a Service to run MediaPlayer and play the music. The Service will run in parallel to your Android process and will not effect it's performance.

Service documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

SoundPool is best used for playing short sound clips like sound effects as you've already noticed :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Read the section "Extending the Service class" in the link I posted. It details how you can send and receive data between your service and your main process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352758/android-making-thread-in-service?noredirect=1#comment39528170_25352758 can you look my code i'm beginner and i can't to understand all

Comment: I had implement this from section "Extending the Service class",but same problem my application with lot of sprites use less CPU than media server with three sounds(total size less than 0.5 mb)